# graphql can not reuse the type ,and type is not as input and return

Tags: graphql

such as when I defined a type.

```
type user{
  name :String!,
  age : Int! 
}
```

and the user type only uses in the return. can not be input.

when the type has more properties. such as 10,15, and so on.

```
type user{
  name: String!,
  age: Int!,
  ...
}
```

the user is input and returned.

I have to write more code and have to define the input type which properties are the same as the return.

ext.

```
type Query{
 getUser(u:User):User
}
```

if the user has 22 and more properties, the code is excessive. the input and return have to define two type.

I think the code can be reused .and input can as return. return as input. the input can be the same as return.

Comment: Yes, in GraphQL input and output object types are different. The reason is that output types can have arguments, computed fields etc. In more serious APIs, types seldomly match your underlying database models. If you look for a way to quickly create a GraphQL API with very little code, you can check out one of the various SDL to DB tools like Hasura, Graphbase, Hygraph, FaunaDB, ...